# Splicing a sequence with a sequence of positions

Tags: python, sequence

How can we splice a sequence with another sequence of the positions we want to splice?

---

For example, consider

```
a = [1,"A", 34, -123, "Hello", 12]
b = [0, 2, 5]
```

And the aim is to get:

```
[1, 34, 12]
```

The only solutions I could find was

```
c = []
for i in b:
   c.append(a[i])
```

Is there a solution that doesn't require to loop in Python?

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate but I failed to find the info by myself. Sorry!

Comment: I'd call it cherry-picking, not splicing.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It is a duplicate indeed. I am voting to close. Thank you

Comment: `map(a.__getitem__, b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following is the shortest form possible:

```
c = [a[i] for i in b]
```